# Why does list of `(read)` values come in reverse order in Scheme?

Tags: list, file, io, scheme

I'm trying to read from a file in Scheme and I wonder why one needs to reverse the list after getting values with `(read)` or `(read-line)`. Example:

```
]=> (list 1 (read) 2 (read) 3)
Hello
world

;Value 39: (1 world 2 hello 3)
```

Why does "world" precede "hello" in resulting list? Cheers.

Comment: What dialect of Scheme do you use? Does it specify order of procedure arguments evaluation?

Comment: I'm on MIT-Scheme 9.1.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evaluation order of arguments is by the standard undefined. Here are the [part from the R6RS report](http://www.r6rs.org/corrected/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-12.html#node_idx_292):

> Note:‌ In contrast to other dialects of Lisp, **the order of evaluation
>   is unspecified**, and the operator expression and the operand
>   expressions are always evaluated with the same evaluation rules.
>
> Although the order of evaluation is otherwise unspecified, the effect
>   of any concurrent evaluation of the operator and operand expressions
>   is constrained to be consistent with some sequential order of
>   evaluation. The order of evaluation may be chosen differently for each
>   procedure call.

Here is an example:

```
(define (debug x)
  (display x)
  x)

(define (add x y)
  (debug (+ (debug x) (debug y))))

(add (add 3 4)
     (add 5 6))
; ==> 18
```

Here are the possible outcomes from the `display` calls:

```
347561171118 ; strictly left to right
651143771118 ; strictly right to left
561134771118 ; ltr in add, rtl in call to add (consistent)
437651111718 ; rtl in add, ltr in call to add (consistent)
```

As examples I know MIT Scheme does strictly right to left while DrRacket does strictly left to right. Ikarus did the third one.

The reason to underspecify these is to allow for unknown optimizations at the time specification is written. It's not often the order is important, expecially if you write it idiomatic. If you need the proper order you can write it like this:

```
(let ((r1 (read)))
  (let ((r2 (read)))
    (list 1 r1 2 r2 3)))
```

Since the bindings always are evaluated before the body you are safe. This has a shotcut so you can write it as `let*`:

```
(let* ((r1 (read))
       (r2 (read)))
  (list 1 r1 2 r2 3))
```

Comment: "may be chosen differently for each procedure call" i.e. 561143771118 is also allowed, it would seem. (?)

Comment: @WillNess You cannot have `56` and then `43` `(+ (debug x) (debug y))` would not be consistent.  I corrected my answer since its only 4 possible outcomes instead of my assumed 8.

Comment: @Sylwester Why should it be consistent? *The order of evaluation may be chosen differently for each procedure call.* It say procedure *call*, but not procedure *call-site*. As I understand it, conforming implementation allowed to evaluate arguments in different order for each call even in the same call-site.

Comment: @PetSerAl `+` is a procedure. `(+ ...)` is a procedure call. A procedure call and call site would be the same in the way I understand it or else the "constrained to be consistent with some sequential order of evaluation" makes no sense. I might be wrong in my interpretation as lots of implementations do differ in other aspects, but I have not seen any that break my interpretation of this part before. Do you have an example?

Comment: *constrained to be consistent with some sequential order of evaluation* was said about ***concurrent** evaluation*. As I understand, that means `(add (add 3 4) (add 5 6))` are not allowed to produce something like `354671171118`. It is not allowed to interleave side effects of evaluation of `(add 3 4)` and `(add 5 6)` even if them evaluated concurrently. But I do not see any rule that prohibit `(let f ((n 4)) (when (positive? n) (add 1 2) (f (sub1 n))))` to produce `123213123213`. Well, I agree that likely no implementation actually do that, but that does not mean, that it is not allowed.

Comment: @PetSerAl that's my reading of it, too. "The order of evaluation may be chosen differently for each procedure call" i.e. each call to `add` is free to choose its order of arguments evaluation, as long as it is "consistent with some sequential order of evaluation" i.e. arguments must not be evaluated concurrently; left-to-right or right-to-left, doesn't matter, as long as it is something sequential, at least observably so.

Answer (score 0):

The order in which the arguments to a function are evaluated is not defined by the Scheme language. That is, when evaluating `(f (g) (h))`, it is not defined whether the call to `g` happens before or after the call to `h` (only that both happen before the call to `f`).

So for your code that means that it is undefined which of the two calls to `read` happen first. In some implementations, you might get the order you expect, while in others you get the one you're seeing here.

In order to force the calls to happen in the order you want, you should use `let` or `define` to store the results of `read` in variables before the call to `list`.

Comment: I presume the order in which calls to `(read)` will happen are pretty well defined... See the `(cons)` example around. Thank you.

Comment: @AlexFortuna It's not well-defined at all. Just try it in different implementations: For example racket and guile will evaluate it left-to-right and chez right-to-left.

Comment: @AlexFortuna See for example [this](https://ideone.com/I2MhNE) versus [this](https://ideone.com/mzuHPG) (different Scheme implementations, same code, same input, different output).

Comment: That's interesting. I thought building lists from `(cons)` was sort of canonical based on old-school Lisp and Scheme docs like MIT-Scheme etc.. Looks that unspecified evaluation order is indeed a fact.

Comment: @AlexFortuna Sure, but the fact that `list` calls `cons` doesn't make any difference. `(cons (read) (cons (read) '()))` has exactly the same undefined evaluation order as `(list (read) (read))`. `cons` isn't any different from `list` in that regard: it may evaluate its arguments in any order.

Comment: "use `let` to store the [interim] results..." otherwise known as code in [SSA-form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form).

Answer (score -2):

I think I got it. Since each list in Scheme is in fact a recursion of `(cons ...)`, above mentioned list is actually a:

```
(cons
  1
  (cons
    (read)        ; (2)
    (cons
      2
      (cons
        (read)    ; (1)
        (cons
          3
          '()
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Thus it becomes clear why `(read)` marked (1) gets evaluated before `(read)` marked (2).

Comment: `list` is a procedure, not a macro, so its arguments are evaluated before they're substituted in its body. Also even in your expanded version, the order would still be undefined because you don't know whether the first argument of `cons` is evaluated before the second or vice-versa. In fact I'm not sure why you even claim that this version makes it clear that 1 happens before 2. It's not any more or less clear than in the `list` version: if arguments are evaluated left-to-right, 2 will be evaluated first, if right-to-left, 1 will be evalauted first.

Comment: Looks that this code will run differently based on Scheme implementation. [guile 2.0.13](https://ideone.com/CbO5Po); [chicken 4.11.0](https://ideone.com/amEPjq).

Comment: That is not strange because the answer is competly wrong. `list` evaluates all arguments before doing any `cons` and when it does the side effects have been executed in the order the implementation chose.

Comment: In lazy languages like Haskell, your reasoning would be correct. Though in pure languages like Haskell, a call to `read` can't be freely mixed with a call to `cons`, but that's another problem.